# Pass Defined Variable from VBA to SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've defined AllParts as a variable in VBA. As formatted in SQL (see below), I'm getting an error. New to this and can't seem to tweak appropriately. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
and   msikp.concatenated_segments in (" & AllParts & ")
```

Comment: One line is not enough code - post the rest and don't ask us to guess...

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your *full* VBA line looks something like this?

The actual quotation marks used for SQL strings will vary by the driver/DBMS. For SQL server, single-quotes should do:

```
Dim AllParts As String
Dim SQL As String

AllParts = "'Foo', 'Bar'"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM segments AS msikp " & _
      "WHERE msikp.id > 0 " & _
      "and   msikp.concatenated_segments in (" & AllParts & ")"
```

For Access, escaped double-quotes work better:

```
Dim AllParts As String
Dim SQL As String

AllParts = """Foo"", ""Bar"""
SQL = "SELECT * FROM segments AS msikp " & _
      "WHERE msikp.id > 0 " & _
      "and   msikp.concatenated_segments in (" & AllParts & ")"
```

If it does, then it should work, but beware that building SQL with concatenation of inputs can expose you to SQL Injection attacks.